# How to locate elements in AG-Grid? if there is no ids available

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ag-grid

I’m facing a challenge in locating the elements in AG Grid. As I unable to locate the elements in the grid.  Can we create the user define locator in selenium to locate the elements in AG Grid. Or Kindly suggest any other alternative to work with it. And it is prohibited to use either of the locators xpath, css selector, name, class in our project.
One more thing, is it possible to .
Kindly refer to the attached screenshots for the reference. Do let me know if you need any further information from my side. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried locating the elements with other locators
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post html code, not picture.

Comment: Why is it _it is prohibited to use either of the locators xpath, css selector, name, class_?

Answer (score 2):

below xpath should work,

//div[@col-id='locationName'][contains(text(),'Opthamology')]

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use anything but [id](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) - you should ask your application developers to add unique identifiers for each element.

If for some reason it is not possible - you can use [WebDriver.executeScript()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) function which allows executing arbitrary [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) code which in its turn can [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) various selector expressions, for example [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727), the relevant syntax for your case would be something like:

```
WebElement someElement = (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return document.evaluate('//div[contains(text(),\"Opthamology\")]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;");
```